# Broadcast of Intent: RegisterUponInstallReceiver, Native ANR, No Java Stack

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, android-anr-dialog, android-native-library

Once again Google/Android9 crashes somewhere in native code library without giving any idea through Java stack trace or otherwise about where it happened and why.

In my case it happened during "REGISTER_AGENT" intent issued by Samsung SAP library.

Probably it's related to Samsung SAP library, but it's specific to Android9 only and it doesn't happen very often.

Any hint and help are appreciated.

```
Broadcast of Intent { act=com.samsung.accessory.action.REGISTER_AGENT flg=0x30 pkg=[package_name] cmp=[package_name]/com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.RegisterUponInstallReceiver }
com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.RegisterUponInstallReceiver


"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x75952fb8 self=0x7368414c00
  | sysTid=16534 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73eee21560
  | state=S schedstat=( 92637885 21726999 102 ) utm=1 stm=7 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd3ecd000-0x7fd3ecf000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 00000000000712e0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
  #01  pc 00000000000141c0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+144)
  #02  pc 000000000001408c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)
  #03  pc 000000000012c25c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:181)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6990)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" tid=2 Native
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132001a0 self=0x7361e24400
  | sysTid=16540 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7361dff4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 1490961 201962 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7361d01000-0x7361d03000 stackSize=1021KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001eeac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d7c24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 00000000004b6614  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+260)
  #03  pc 00000000004b5b6c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+124)
  #04  pc 00000000004b561c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
  #05  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #06  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" tid=4 Waiting
"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132002b0 self=0x73684e2000
  | sysTid=16542 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7350ed74f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 1160387 6055884 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7350dd4000-0x7350dd6000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0727dab7> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:178)
- locked <0x0727dab7> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" tid=5 Waiting
"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13200338 self=0x73684e3800
  | sysTid=16544 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7350ccb4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 428733 6635577 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7350bc8000-0x7350bca000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x01261224> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded (Daemons.java:297)
- locked <0x01261224> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:277)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"FinalizerDaemon" tid=6 Waiting
"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132003c0 self=0x73684e2c00
  | sysTid=16543 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7350dd14f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 1754693 6156655 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7350cce000-0x7350cd0000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0294e18d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:422)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:188)
- locked <0x0294e18d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove (ReferenceQueue.java:209)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:232)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"Binder:16534_1" tid=8 Native
"Binder:16534_1" prio=5 tid=8 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13200448 self=0x735e88d000
  | sysTid=16546 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73509c14f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 1058729 78231 14 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x73508c6000-0x73508c8000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 00000000000713cc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 0000000000029c48  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
  #02  pc 000000000005ac9c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
  #03  pc 000000000005ae78  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
  #04  pc 000000000005b5cc  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+60)
  #05  pc 000000000007c090  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
  #07  pc 00000000000bcbf4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #09  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Binder:16534_2" tid=9 Native
"Binder:16534_2" prio=5 tid=9 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132004d0 self=0x735fd04000
  | sysTid=16547 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73508c34f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 5113655 9872309 15 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x73507c8000-0x73507ca000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 00000000000713cc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 0000000000029c48  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
  #02  pc 000000000005ac9c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
  #03  pc 000000000005ae78  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
  #04  pc 000000000005b5cc  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+60)
  #05  pc 000000000007c090  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
  #07  pc 00000000000bcbf4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #09  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Profile Saver" tid=10 Native
"Profile Saver" daemon prio=5 tid=10 Native
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13200558 self=0x7361e29800
  | sysTid=16548 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x73500034f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 13089538 7896001 11 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x734ff08000-0x734ff0a000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001eeac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d7c24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 000000000032a168  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::Run()+384)
  #03  pc 000000000032d58c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::RunProfileSaverThread(void*)+92)
  #04  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #05  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Timer-0" tid=11 TimedWaiting
"Timer-0" prio=5 tid=11 TimedWaiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132005e0 self=0x735fcae000
  | sysTid=16551 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x734fe5b4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 24982964 11812847 67 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x734fd58000-0x734fd5a000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x062b2f42> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Object.java:422)
  at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop (Timer.java:559)
- locked <0x062b2f42> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
  at java.util.TimerThread.run (Timer.java:512)
"RegistrationThread" tid=12 Waiting
"RegistrationThread" prio=5 tid=12 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132006a8 self=0x73684b3000
  | sysTid=16555 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x734fd554f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 360153 6123923 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x734fc52000-0x734fc54000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait (Native method)
- waiting on <0x07d56b53> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2137)
- locked <0x07d56b53> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:358)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park (LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone (FutureTask.java:450)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:192)
  at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.RegisterUponInstallReceiver$1.run (unavailable)
"RegistreationThread" tid=13 Native
"RegistreationThread" prio=5 tid=13 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13200990 self=0x73684b3c00
  | sysTid=16556 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x734fc4f4f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 8286656 6348153 18 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x734fb4c000-0x734fb4e000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 00000000000713cc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 0000000000029c48  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
  #02  pc 000000000005ac9c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
  #03  pc 000000000005bb70  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+360)
  #04  pc 000000000005b890  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+176)
  #05  pc 0000000000051560  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+72)
  #06  pc 000000000013c110  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android_os_BinderProxy_transact(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+152)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:1142)
  at com.samsung.accessory.api.ISAFrameworkManagerV2$Stub$Proxy.registerComponent (unavailable)
  at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAdapter.a (unavailable)
- locked <0x01c42c90> (a com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAdapter)
  at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.j$a.a (unavailable)
  at com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.j$a.call (unavailable)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
"Binder:16534_3" tid=14 Native
"Binder:16534_3" prio=5 tid=14 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13201170 self=0x735e918000
  | sysTid=16617 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x734fb494f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 4330424 370692 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x734fa4e000-0x734fa50000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 00000000000713cc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
  #01  pc 0000000000029c48  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
  #02  pc 000000000005ac9c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
  #03  pc 000000000005ae78  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+24)
  #04  pc 000000000005b5cc  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+60)
  #05  pc 000000000007c090  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+24)
  #06  pc 000000000000fb80  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
  #07  pc 00000000000bcbf4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #09  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"Signal Catcher" tid=3 Runnable
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x13200228 self=0x7368416400
  | sysTid=16541 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7361cfe4f0
  | state=R schedstat=( 53512999 6126116 5 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7361c03000-0x7361c05000 stackSize=1009KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  #00  pc 00000000003cb35c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
  #01  pc 000000000049aca8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+352)
  #02  pc 00000000004b4d9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+844)
  #03  pc 00000000004adadc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+476)
  #04  pc 00000000004acec0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+1120)
  #05  pc 00000000004ac974  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+884)
  #06  pc 000000000047c26c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+188)
  #07  pc 00000000004881bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit()+1468)
  #08  pc 0000000000486ea4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+380)
  #09  pc 0000000000084df8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #10  pc 0000000000023ac4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"HeapTaskDaemon" tid=7 
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WaitingForTaskProcessor
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x132011f8 self=0x735fc37c00
  | sysTid=16545 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7350bc54f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 49512888 1873077 14 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7350ac2000-0x7350ac4000 stackSize=1041KB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001eeac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d7c24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 0000000000230820  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::GetTask(art::Thread*)+504)
  #03  pc 0000000000231098  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+96)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks (Native method)
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal (Daemons.java:475)
  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run (Daemons.java:103)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
© 2019 Google · Mobile App · Help · Site Terms · Privacy · Developer Distribution Agreement
```

Comment: Same ANR, something new?

Comment: No, I don't have any updates